# Javascript - if statement error

Tags: javascript

Wondering if someone can steer me into the right direction, I'm trying to use Javascript to make a little game to help me learn. Essentially I declare all my variables which I want to change outside of my function so they act global, which works in the code but the if statement seems to be not proving successful, I cant seem to correct this as tutorials point to my code as correct, please see code below;

```
var Refresh;
Refresh = "InActive";

var Counter;
Counter = 0;

var StartTime;


function StartGame() {
    var StartDate;
    StartDate = new Date();
    StartTime = d.getTime();
    Refresh = "Active";
}


function FunctionB1() {
    if (Refresh == "Active"){
        document.getElementById("Bean1").style.display = "None";
        Counter ++;
        document.getElementById("BeanCount").innerHTML = Counter + " Out of 150";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `var Refresh` declared anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: @GlenDespaux The very first line ...

Comment: Ah I see, it was not put into the code block. Sorry about that

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: You need to call the functions for them to fire.

Comment: What exactly isn’t working?

Comment: Any console errors?where u r invoking these functions?? How comes d.getTime() without d 

Comment: The d.gettime() refers to a previous named variable i have since renamed startdate

Comment: Pro-tip: learn to use [your console.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) It would have reported this error to you and you can use it to output information that will help with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `d.getTime();` to `StartDate.getTime();` to reflect the change in variable name.

```
function StartGame() {
StartTime = new Date().getTime();
Refresh = "Active";
}
```

JSFiddle: [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/n52pkLew/4/)

Edited to include Xufox's improvement.

Comment: This could’ve just been `StartTime = new Date().getTime();` `Refresh = "Active";`. No need for unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the variable `Refresh` from `StartGame()` function.
It would look something like this:

```
function StartGame() {
    var StartDate;
    StartDate = new Date();
    StartTime = d.getTime();
    Refresh = "Active";
    return Refresh;
}

function FunctionB1() {
    var startRefresh = StartGame();
    if (startRefresh == "Active"){
        document.getElementById("Bean1").style.display = "None";
        Counter ++;
        document.getElementById("BeanCount").innerHTML = Counter + " Out of 150";
    }
}

FunctionB1(); // Call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh Variable becomes accessible after you call StartGame(). You cannot access Refresh variable in FunctionB1 as it has not be declared yet.
Try like this

```
function StartGame() {
    Refresh = "Active";
}

function FunctionB1() {
    if (Refresh == "Active"){
        console.log('done');
    }
}

function Game() {
    StartGame()
    FunctionB1()
    console.log(Refresh) // Active
};
```